# Proving $n^3 \in \omega(n^2 (\log n)^2)$

Tags: asymptotics

I have

$$n^3 > M  n^2(\log n)^2$$
$$n > M (\log n)^2$$
(Since $\log n < n$.)
$$n > M (n)^2$$
$$1/n > M$$
$$1/M > n$$

Therefore define n0 to be any value less than $1/M$.

But plotting the graph on Desmos does not seem correct. I think I may have gone wrong with my algebra somewhere?

Comment: Please use mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @KamalSaleh Please, if you edit the question to add MathJax, make sure you do it properly.

Comment: @jjagmath It was hard for me to do it because of the blockquote. So I edited the title.

Comment: @KamalSaleh And your edition in the title was not correct. You leave it as ” Proving n³ \in \omega $(n^2 (\log n)^2)$. ”

Comment: @jjagmath Really? Well, sorry about that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first steps look good. You show that the inequality you need is equivalent to $M \log(n)^2 < n$.

After that, you use $\log(n) < n$ to conclude that if $M n^2 < n$ then you'll also get $M \log(n)^2 < n$. That is true, but it's not useful: no matter how you pick $M$, it will not be true that $M n^2 < n$ for large $n$. So you need to use a different strategy to find $M$ such that $M \log(n)^2 < n$ for all large $n$.

It's hard to hint a good strategy because I don't know what results you've proven about $\log$. But one commonly known fact is that $\log(n) \in O(n^\alpha)$ for all $\alpha > 0$. If you use this fact for $\alpha = \frac 1 4$ then you'll be able to finish your proof after a bit more algebra.

Good luck :)

---

EDIT: **OP added the following in a comment:** (slightly edited)

Using that I was able to get
$$\begin{align}
&& n &> M \log(n)^2 \\
\impliedby && n &> M (n^{1/4})^2 \\
\iff && n &> M n^{1/2} \\
\iff && n^{1/2} &> M \\
\iff && n &> M^2
\end{align}$$
So then $n_0$ would be any value greater than $M^2$ ?

**My response:**
That is almost exactly right, except you should remember the exact definition of $\log(n) \in O(n^{1/4})$. It means that there exists some $K$ and $c$ such that for all $n \ge K$, $\log(n) \le c n^{1/4}$. So your work above would be very slightly different:
$$\begin{align}
&& n &> M \log(n)^2 \\
\impliedby && n &> M \left(c n^{1/4}\right)^2
\end{align}$$
where the last step is only valid for $n \ge K$. Now you could continue from there. At the end you'll find some condition for $n_0$ again, but then you should make sure you choose a final $n_0$ that satisfies the condition you derive AND has $n_0 \ge K$, so that this first step stays valid.

Comment: Using that I was able to get 
n > M * (n^1/4)^2
n > M *n^1/2
n^1/2 > M
n > M^2

So then n0 would be any value greater than M^2 ?

Comment: Nice. That's just about right but there's one detail you're missing. I edited my answer to cover that part.